How do I tell what caused an internal compiler error in Android Studio?
I am building an app in Android Studio Hedgehog with Kotlin.  On my latest attempt to build, I got an internal compiler error.  I recently added Room and KSP to the project, so I assume I did something wrong adding one of them, but I have no idea what to look at to find the problem.
My guess is I added something to the gradle files wrong because I had a lot of trouble finding documentation on how to do it.  How can I tell where I went wrong when I get an error like this?  The log looks like this:
  kotlin version: 1.9.0
error message: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilationContext.<init>(org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.storage.FileToPathConverter, org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.storage.FileToPathConverter, boolean, org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.CompilationTransaction, org.jetbrains.kotlin.build.report.ICReporter, boolean, boolean, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker)'
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.IncrementalContext.<init>(IncrementalContext.kt:76)
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.AbstractKotlinSymbolProcessingExtension$doAnalysis$2.invoke(KotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.kt:189)
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.AbstractKotlinSymbolProcessingExtension$doAnalysis$2.invoke(KotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.kt:186)
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.AbstractKotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.handleException(KotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.kt:410)
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.AbstractKotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.doAnalysis(KotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.kt:186)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:256)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:247)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:87)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:168)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1497)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


The gradle.build file for the project looks like this:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.22-1.0.17" apply false
}

The gradle.build file for the app/module is as follows:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.prayeveryday"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.prayeveryday"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    val roomVersion = "2.6.1"

    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-adaptive:1.0.0-alpha06")
    implementation("com.kizitonwose.calendar:compose:2.5.0")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}

In case it's a problem with my implementation, here's where I implement the database with Room:
package com.example.prayeveryday

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import androidx.room.Query
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import java.util.Date

@Database(entities = [PrayerRequest::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() { // defines the database
    abstract fun PrayerRequestDao() : PrayerRequestDao
}

@Entity(tableName = "prayerRequests")
data class PrayerRequest( // defines the data class the database stores
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Label") val label: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Date") val date: Date,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Summary") val summary: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Details") val details: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Repeating") val repeating: Boolean
    )

@Dao
interface PrayerRequestDao { // defines methods that can be used to interact with the database
    @Insert
    fun insert(prayerRequest: PrayerRequest)

    @Delete
    fun delete(prayerRequest: PrayerRequest)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM prayerRequests")
    fun getAll(): List<PrayerRequest>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM prayerRequests WHERE date = :date")
    fun getRequestsFromDate(date: Date): PrayerRequest
}

What did I do wrong, and how do you tell where you went wrong if you get an internal compiler error?

The error
Your problem may be that you are using inconsistent Kotlin and KSP versions. The first part of the KSP version must be the same as the Kotlin version.
To stick to Kotlin version 1.9.0 you need KSP version 1.9.0-1.0.13 (see Maven Central). So you need instead:
plugins {
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.0-1.0.13" apply false
}

How I identified this could be the issue
First and foremost, I looked carefully at the stack trace. This shows exactly where the error arose. The error arose in KSP code, so this gave a major hint something was wrong with the KSP setup. The stack trace also showed there was a Kotlin compiler argument involved, so it looked like the Kotlin compiler was involved as well.
Turning to your build setup, I then looked to check to see if there were any obvious errors. As a user of KSP, I know that you are supposed to use a KSP version that matches the Kotlin version, something that is common across Kotlin libraries and indeed more generally when libraries are closely related (KSP is essentially a modification of the Kotlin compilation process, after all).
I couldn't then be sure that this was the source of your problems without attempting the fix, but it seemed likely enough that I posted the answer.
Had this not worked then it could have been necessary to dig deeper, perhaps by very carefully comparing your setup to published documentation, or even stepping through the build using a debugger.

Thanks, that did get it to compile and run.  How do I know where to look for the issue in the future?

You need to be aware that library versions need to be chosen with care when those libraries rely on each other. In such cases libraries will normally declare in their release notes for each version what versions of other libraries they are compatible with. In this case it's a bit simpler because both of these libraries are Kotlin-related libraries, so it's natural that they must use the same Kotlin version. It's not as mysterious or magical as it might appear - you'll get used to this issue. On another note, if you could accept the answer since it solved your issue I would be grateful.

Oh, the other thing was looking at the stack trace. Your error came from the KSP library code, and it involved a Kotlin compiler argument. So for those reasons it also wasn't a big leap to spot it was something to do with your KSP configuration, and even more how it interacted with the Kotlin compiler.

Could you add that to your answer?  It helps answer the other half of my question about how to tell where I went wrong.

Yes, apologies for that I was so eager to get to the issue that i didn't appreciate the full scope of your question.
